@RemoteAction - static method variable access
is there any way to access the variable outside the method and inside the same class?
'selectedvalues' List variable is declared as static variable in same class
@RemoteAction 
public static List<String> GetJSVal(List<String> jslist){
   
    system.debug('JS list'+jslist);
    selectedvalues.addall(jslist);
 
    return selectedvalues;
}


Is your "selectedvalues" variable going to change across multiple Remote methods or just this one method? And is that variable has some default values?

No, it's for only one remote method and will not change any any other calls,. And there is no default value for it.

static variables are also transient. They are not part of the page's state, and do not persist across transactions. Instead, you'll want to use apex:actionFunction if you need to store those values across transactions, within the view state.

you are right, we can easily achive this using  apex:actionFunction ,thanks
